# Bukkit countdown timer starts counting down infinite (2,1,-1,-2 etc)

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

So i got this problem when one - two+ players are online the countdown timer goes in minus like this 4,3,2,1,0 -1,-2,-3 etc.
Does anyone know how i can fix this, been struggling with it for quite a long time now :P

Here is my countdown class:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (timeUntilStart == 0) {
        if (!Game.canStart()) {
            if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() <= 2) {
            plugin.restartCountdown();
            ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "Not enough players to start. Countdown will");
            ChatUtilities.broadcast(ChatColor.RED + "restart.");
            for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ENDERDRAGON_WINGS, 5, 1);
            return;
        }else{
            if(Game.canStart()) {
                if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() >= 2) {
            Game.start();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    }
    boolean broadcast = false;

    for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        p.setLevel(timeUntilStart);

        if (timeUntilStart < 11  || timeUntilStart == 120 ||timeUntilStart == 60 || timeUntilStart == 30) {
            p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 5, 0);
            if (timeUntilStart == 1) p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.ORB_PICKUP, 5, 1);
            broadcast = true;
        }
    }


    if (broadcast) ChatUtilities.broadcast(String.valueOf(timeUntilStart) + " §6Seconds until the game starts!");{

    }
    {
    timeUntilStart -= 1;   

}
}
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of unnecessary `{}` blocks in your code, especially towards the end. Perhaps it would help to clean up this mess.

Comment: How about using `if (timeUntilStart < 0) {timeUntilStart = 0};` after `timeUntilStart -= 1;` to prevent it from going below zero?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It won't work, or almost we don't know. Note that run() method, it may be run within a BukkitRunnable or a task. So if you set the timeUntilStart value to 0, the task is still running so it will still subtract 1 to the variable. So, he should use Thread#stop or other similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

The only case in which your method returns and `timeUtilStart` is not decremented is

```
timeUntilStart == 0 && !Game.canStart() && Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() <= 2
```

As defined by the first three `if` blocks in your code.
This explains why your countdown does not stop when you have 3 or more players around.

I believe this mistake happened because of messy `{}` blocks and indentation. Take a step back and closely read the code you wrote again and fix brackets as well as indentation.

Good formatting is not a pointless chore, it's an essential tool to help yourself understand what you already wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the bukkit scheduler? People tend to forget that bukkit's API can handle countdowns very well. Just call the scheduler with this

```
myInteger = Bukkit's.getScheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new runnable(), 0L, 20L)
```

Put your JavaPlugin extension class in as plugin, use runnable adding unimplemented methods, 0L is ticks before first run, 20L is ticks between each run.

Cancel the countdown like this

```
Bukkit's.getScheduler.cancelTask(myInteger)
```